# How can Bender not know how robot procreation works?

Tags: futurama, sexuality

After watching the first part of the new season premiere, something struck me:

> After impregnating and having a child by a vending machine, Bender is quite surprised. However, as seen in The Beast with a Billion Backs; he already has a son, that appears, knowing what we now do, to have been conceived and born in a similar fashion.

How can he not know how this works, or more to the point, fail to even realize that it is a thing?

**Edit:** Realizing that the question is, in its current form, somewhat lacking; I'll amend it:

Is there any observed in-universe reason for his failing to keep track of such an utterly basic element of his own "biology"?

Comment: There are women who have become pregnant more than once who don't understand how they got pregnant... Your mistake is in assuming that sentient beings behave with the same logic you posses.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Be that as it may; Bender doesn't just fail to understand *how* it works, he fails to understand that it is a thing.

Comment: A person who rejects comprehending reality is in a state of denial.

Comment: Someone forgot to sit him down and talk about the bytes and the bits...

Comment: Obviously, the bending school he attended must have had an abstinence-only program instead of comprehensive sex education. I bet he never even saw *Electro Gonhorrhea: The Noisy Killer*.

Comment: @gnovice He raises this point himself. The issue is that he already has a son, which speaks to him at least knowing that it is possible, but that is still something that takes him completely by surprise.

Comment: @Williham: He raised that point himself?! I actually *missed* the episode and was just making a joke. Maybe I should get a job writing for them. ;)

Comment: Simple, Bender is programmed to bend not to multiply.

Comment: In [Kif Gets Knocked Up a Notch](http://theinfosphere.org/Kif_Gets_Knocked_Up_a_Notch), Bender shows massive impatience at hearing about how Kif's species reproduces.  Maybe he just hates hearing about reproduction.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that Bender has sex (?) a lot, considering that in the beginning of the episode he brought two other lady bots home, yet he has never uploaded his code to another robot, it can probably be assumed that a robot's birth control is the responsibility of the woman robot.

We do see twice in one episode that the soda machine robot got pregnant, which suggests that she is very lax about using her birth control. Perhaps she accepts every git pull request that is sent her way, while the other robots that Bender is with are more choosey about this?

Since it is the responsibility of the lady robots to use birth control in the Futurama universe, perhaps the boy robots aren't educated about birth control as much. As one commenter stated, there are women who have become pregnant more than once and still don't understand how that has happened; in our society, our main form of birth control is the responsibility of men, so it's understandable that a poorly-educated women would be oblivious to this fact.

Comment: Bender was never given sex education at all, on account of his mother was a religious fundamentalist. However, the problem isn't that Bender isn't aware of how it happens, that's fine. The problem is that he doesn't seem to be aware that it is even possible.