# How could Bender have a child?

Tags: futurama

In [The Bots and the Bees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bots_and_the_Bees) somehow Bender fathers a child.

How is that possible?

It was explained that in the 31st century they were programmed to procreate, but why hasn't this ever been brought up before?

Comment: When a manbot and a fembot love each other *very* much...

Comment: @Keen LOL. Don't you think you are funny ^_^

Comment: @Keen Don't think it, know it!

Comment: repeat to yourself: "It's just a show..."

Answer (score 5):

It's explained very clearly in the show:

Data is uploaded from the manbot to the fembot, containing design specs. The fembot then merges this information with her own design specs, and builds and "births" a robot designed to "grow". Presumably, all fembots that support this feature have a built-in robot factory.

[I've also asked about some issues with this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18830), but it *has* been brought up by the show previously, in The Beast with a Billion Backs, Bender is shown to have a son, whom he promptly delivers to the Robot Devil.